# problems inserting other characters postgres database through scrapy

Tags: python, postgresql, scrapy

Hello everyone I'm starting with scrapy and I'm  doing scrapy to a supermarket but the urls and product names have characters like "ñ" so when I'm scraping it it stop saving me those information in my database and it just save the info until before it bumps into the url or name with that character "ñ" specifically I've read a lot about encode and decode functions and I've tried many solutions people posted here but it doesn't work.

SCRAPY CODE

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import scrapy   
import psycopg2   #Para establecer conexion con la base de datos.

from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule   #Para la creacion del bot y sus reglas de busqueda   
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor   #Para extraer link de las paginas visitadas
import time
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


# #Creando la conexion.
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="namedb", user="postgres", password="root", host="127.0.0.1", port="5432")
# #Creando cursor.
cur = conn.cursor()


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Funciones


def leer_datos(nombre_archivo):
    """Lee un archivo txt y devuelve un array donde cada posicion es una fila del archivo.
    Argumentos: 
    nombre_archivo: String. No debe tener la extension. 
    """

    array = []
    archivo = open(nombre_archivo + '.txt','r')
    linea = archivo.readline()
    while linea != '':
    # Lee el archivo por lineas y las agrega al array.

        cadena = linea.strip('\n')  #Saca el valor '\n' de la linea
        array.append(cadena)    #Agrega la linea al array
        linea = archivo.readline()
    archivo.close()  # Cierra archivo
    return array


def insertar_datos(nombre_archivo,cadena):
    """Inserta un string en una fila de un archivo txt.
    Argumentos:
    nombre_archivo: String. No debe tener la extension.
    cadena: String a escribir en el archivo.
    """

    archivo = open(nombre_archivo + '.txt', "r+")
    contenido = archivo.read()  #Lee todo el contenido y el cursor queda al final.
    final_de_archivo = archivo.tell()   #Obtiene la posicion del cursor. Se encuentra en el final (ver linea anterior).
    archivo.seek(final_de_archivo)  #El cursor queda al final del archivo y se evita que vuelva al inicio al escribir.
    archivo.write(cadena)
    archivo.write('\n')
    archivo.close()


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Clases

#Clase para la extracion de elementos.



class LiderItem(scrapy.Item):

    name_prod = scrapy.Field()
    pricing = scrapy.Field()
    category = scrapy.Field()
    description = scrapy.Field()
    supermarket = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()


#Clase principal del programa.
class LiderSpider(CrawlSpider):

    #Configuracion inicial
    custom_settings = {
        "CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT":25,   #Cantidad de elementos a buscar. Comienza a contar desde el 0.
        "CONCURRENT_REQUESTS":1,   #Cantidad de url que puede visitar a la vez.
        "CONCURRENT_ITEMS":1,   #Cantidad de elementos que puede visitar a la vez.
    }
    name = 'Lider'  #Nombre del bot
    allowed_domain = ['www.lider.cl']   #Dominios permitidos para las url que puede visitar.


    start_urls = ['https://www.lider.cl/supermercado/category/Despensa/Pastas-y-Salsas/_/N-pgxorj']

    #Leyendo el archivo "visitados.txt". En caso de no existir se crea.
    file = open("Lider_visitados.txt", "a+") 
    datos_visitados = file.read()
    file.close()

    #Obteniendo las url visitadas.
    if datos_visitados == '':
        url_visitadas = None
    else:
        url_visitadas = []
        url_visitadas = leer_datos("Lider_visitados")   #Se reciben las url visitadas desde el archivo visitados.txt

    #Reglas para la extraccion de url.
    rules = (

        #deny no permite que visite las url que ya ha procesado. restrict_xpaths le restringe moverse horizontalmente solo por las siguentes paginas.
        Rule(LinkExtractor(deny = (url_visitadas), restrict_xpaths = ( '//*[@id="paginationBox"]/nav/ul[2]/li[6]/a'))),

        #restrict_xpaths le restringe moverse verticalmente solo por los item de la pagina actual.
        Rule(LinkExtractor( deny = (url_visitadas), restrict_xpaths = ('//*[starts-with(@class,"product-link")]')),

        #Una vez que consigue las url llama mediante callback a la funcion 'parse_item' para procesar y extraer los datos.
                            callback = 'parse_item', follow = False)
    )


    def parse_item(self, response):
        """Recibe una pagina y extrae los datos para luego guardarlos en la base de datos."""

        item = LiderItem()

        #Extrayendo informacion.
        direccion_url = response.url
        item['name_prod'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//span[@class="product-descript"]/text())').extract_first()
        item['pricing']  = response.xpath('normalize-space(//p[@class="price"])').extract_first()
        item['category'] = 'salsas'
        item['description'] = 'ninguna'
        item['supermarket'] = 'lider'
        item['url'] = direccion_url.encode("utf-8")



        print("\n >>>> EL NOMBRE ES: {0} \n LA URL ES: {1} \n\n".format(item['name_prod'].encode("utf-8"), item['url'].encode("utf-8")))
        time.sleep(5)

        #Preparando sentencia para ingresar datos en base de datos.
        valores = "INSERT INTO products(nombre,precio,categoria,descripcion,supermercado,url) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);"
        data = (item['name_prod'],item['pricing'],item['category'],item['description'],item['supermarket'],item['url'])


        try:
            #Insertando datos en base de datos.
            cur.execute(valores,data)
            conn.commit()

            #Registrando la url procesada en archivo de url visitadas.
            insertar_datos("Lider_visitados",direccion_url)

            print("Datos insertados correctamente.\n")
        except:
            print("NO se han insertado.")
            print("---------------------")
        yield item
```

Basically what this code is doing is that go to the page I gave it and it save the info, these are saved in a txt file and are tried to be saved in my database and every time it's run this code it use that txt file to verify if that product was already scraped for don't save it in the database again

FOR EXAMPLE:
it works well  but when it bumps into this link:

[https://www.lider.cl/supermercado/product/Maggi-Salsa-de-Tomates-Tuco-con-Champiñones-Tarro/813804](https://www.lider.cl/supermercado/product/Maggi-Salsa-de-Tomates-Tuco-con-Champi%C3%B1ones-Tarro/813804)

it fails because I think it has an ñ in the url and in the product name "Salsa de Tomates Tuco con Champiñones" , but the scrapy keeps running it's just that it doesn't save any other information in my database or in my txt file, even when the other products don't have an ñ.

HERE IS THE DATABASE

```
CREATE TABLE products(
    product_id SERIAL,
    nombre VARCHAR(40),
    precio VARCHAR(10),
    categoria VARCHAR(20),
    descripcion VARCHAR(200),
    supermercado VARCHAR(20),
    url VARCHAR(200),

    PRIMARY KEY(product_id)
);
```

Example of what it saves in the txt file

```
https://www.lider.cl/supermercado/product/Carozzi-Pasta-Vitaminizada-Fetuccine-88-Bolsa/299553
https://www.lider.cl/supermercado/product/Carozzi-Fideos-Fusilli-Tricolor-Bolsa/268340
https://www.lider.cl/supermercado/product/Carozzi-Spaghetti-Integral-Vitaminizado-Bolsa/338525
```

THE CMD LOG

```
C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\U\8VO SEMESTRE\Ingeniería de Software II\Proyecto\Scrape
o>scrapy runspider lider2.py
2018-09-17 14:40:59 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started (bot: scrapybo
t)
2018-09-17 14:40:59 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.1.0, libxml2 2.9
.5, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.4.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 17.5.0, Python 2.7.14 |
Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 27 2018, 12:30:54) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)], py
OpenSSL 17.5.0 (OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018), cryptography 2.2.2, Platform Windo
ws-7-6.1.7601-SP1
2018-09-17 14:40:59 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'SPIDER_LOADER_
WARN_ONLY': True, 'CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT': 25, 'CONCURRENT_ITEMS': 1, 'CONCURREN
T_REQUESTS': 1}
2018-09-17 14:40:59 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.closespider.CloseSpider',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2018-09-17 14:41:00 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2018-09-17 14:41:00 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2018-09-17 14:41:00 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2018-09-17 14:41:00 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-09-17 14:41:00 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pag
es/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-09-17 14:41:00 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening o
n 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-09-17 14:41:04 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.l
ider.cl/supermercado/category/Despensa/Pastas-y-Salsas/_/N-pgxorj> (referer: Non
e)
2018-09-17 14:41:04 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET
 https://www.lider.cl/supermercado/product/Malloa-Salsa-de-Tomates-Italiana/3369
> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicate
s)
2018-09-17 14:41:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.l
ider.cl/supermercado/category/Despensa/Pastas-y-Salsas/_/N-pgxorj?No=40&isNavReq
uest=Yes&Nrpp=40&page=2> (referer: https://www.lider.cl/supermercado/category/De
spensa/Pastas-y-Salsas/_/N-pgxorj)
2018-09-17 14:41:09 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.l
ider.cl/supermercado/product/Carozzi-Pasta-Vitaminizada-Fetuccine-88-Bolsa/29955
3> (referer: https://www.lider.cl/supermercado/category/Despensa/Pastas-y-Salsas
/_/N-pgxorj)
Datos insertados correctamente.

2018-09-17 14:41:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.l
ider.cl/supermercado/product/Carozzi-Pasta-Vitaminizada-Fetuccine-88-Bolsa/29955
3>
{'category': 'salsas',
 'description': 'ninguna',
 'name_prod': 'Pasta Vitaminizada Fetuccine 88 Bolsa',
 'pricing': u'$690',
 'supermarket': 'lider',
 'url': 'https://www.lider.cl/supermercado/product/Carozzi-Pasta-Vitaminizada-Fe
tuccine-88-Bolsa/299553'}
2018-09-17 14:41:14 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.l
ider.cl/supermercado/product/Carozzi-Fideos-Fusilli-Tricolor-Bolsa/268340> (refe
rer: https://www.lider.cl/supermercado/category/Despensa/Pastas-y-Salsas/_/N-pgx
orj?No=40&isNavRequest=Yes&Nrpp=40&page=2)
Datos insertados correctamente.

2018-09-17 14:41:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.l
ider.cl/supermercado/product/Carozzi-Fideos-Fusilli-Tricolor-Bolsa/268340>
{'category': 'salsas',
 'description': 'ninguna',
 'name_prod': 'Fideos Fusilli Tricolor Bolsa',
 'pricing': u'$590',
 'supermarket': 'lider',
 'url': 'https://www.lider.cl/supermercado/product/Carozzi-Fideos-Fusilli-Tricol
or-Bolsa/268340'}
2018-09-17 14:41:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.l
ider.cl/supermercado/product/Carozzi-Spaghetti-Integral-Vitaminizado-Bolsa/33852
5> (referer: https://www.lider.cl/supermercado/category/Despensa/Pastas-y-Salsas
/_/N-pgxorj?No=40&isNavRequest=Yes&Nrpp=40&page=2)
Datos insertados correctamente.

2018-09-17 14:41:24 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.l
ider.cl/supermercado/product/Carozzi-Spaghetti-Integral-Vitaminizado-Bolsa/33852
5>
{'category': 'salsas',
 'description': 'ninguna',
 'name_prod': 'Spaghetti Integral Vitaminizado Bolsa',
 'pricing': u'$590',
 'supermarket': 'lider',
 'url': 'https://www.lider.cl/supermercado/product/Carozzi-Spaghetti-Integral-Vi
taminizado-Bolsa/338525'}
2018-09-17 14:41:24 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.l
ider.cl/supermercado/product/Maggi-Salsa-de-Tomates-Tuco-con-Champi%C3%B1ones-Ta
rro/813804> (referer: https://www.lider.cl/supermercado/category/Despensa/Pastas
-y-Salsas/_/N-pgxorj?No=40&isNavRequest=Yes&Nrpp=40&page=2)
NO se han insertado.
---------------------
2018-09-17 14:41:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.l
ider.cl/supermercado/product/Maggi-Salsa-de-Tomates-Tuco-con-Champi%C3%B1ones-Ta
rro/813804>
{'category': 'salsas',
 'description': 'ninguna',
 'name_prod': 'Salsa de Tomates Tuco con Champi\xc3\xb1ones Tarro',
 'pricing': u'$950',
 'supermarket': 'lider',
 'url': 'https://www.lider.cl/supermercado/product/Maggi-Salsa-de-Tomates-Tuco-c
on-Champi%C3%B1ones-Tarro/813804'}
2018-09-17 14:41:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.l
ider.cl/supermercado/product/Pomarola-Salsa-de-Tomates-Casera-con-Cubitos-de-Tom
ates-Doypack/371659> (referer: https://www.lider.cl/supermercado/category/Despen
sa/Pastas-y-Salsas/_/N-pgxorj?No=40&isNavRequest=Yes&Nrpp=40&page=2)
NO se han insertado.
---------------------
2018-09-17 14:41:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.l
ider.cl/supermercado/product/Pomarola-Salsa-de-Tomates-Casera-con-Cubitos-de-Tom
ates-Doypack/371659>
{'category': 'salsas',
 'description': 'ninguna',
 'name_prod': 'Salsa de Tomates Casera con Cubitos de Tomates Doypack',
 'pricing': u'$470',
 'supermarket': 'lider',
 'url': 'https://www.lider.cl/supermercado/product/Pomarola-Salsa-de-Tomates-Cas
era-con-Cubitos-de-Tomates-Doypack/371659'}
2018-09-17 14:41:35 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.l
ider.cl/supermercado/product/Trattoria-Fideos-Fusilli-Bolsa/270370> (referer: ht
tps://www.lider.cl/supermercado/category/Despensa/Pastas-y-Salsas/_/N-pgxorj?No=
40&isNavRequest=Yes&Nrpp=40&page=2)
2018-09-17 14:41:35 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Received SIGINT, shutting down gracef
ully. Send again to force
2018-09-17 14:41:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET ht
tps://www.lider.cl/supermercado/product/Trattoria-Fideos-Fusilli-Bolsa/270370> (
referer: https://www.lider.cl/supermercado/category/Despensa/Pastas-y-Salsas/_/N
-pgxorj?No=40&isNavRequest=Yes&Nrpp=40&page=2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line
 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\off
site.py", line 30, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\ref
erer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\url
length.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\dep
th.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\crawl.py", li
ne 78, in _parse_response
    for requests_or_item in iterate_spider_output(cb_res):
  File "C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\U\8VO SEMESTRE\IngenierÝa de Software II\Proyect
o\Scrapeo\lider2.py", line 156, in parse_item
    time.sleep(5)
IOError: [Errno 4] Interrupted function call
2018-09-17 14:41:35 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (shutdown)
2018-09-17 14:41:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.l
ider.cl/supermercado/product/Lucchetti-Fideos-Cabellitos-Bolsa/296761> (referer:
 https://www.lider.cl/supermercado/category/Despensa/Pastas-y-Salsas/_/N-pgxorj?
No=40&isNavRequest=Yes&Nrpp=40&page=2)
NO se han insertado.
---------------------
2018-09-17 14:41:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.l
ider.cl/supermercado/product/Lucchetti-Fideos-Cabellitos-Bolsa/296761>
{'category': 'salsas',
 'description': 'ninguna',
 'name_prod': 'Fideos Cabellitos Bolsa',
 'pricing': u'$660',
 'supermarket': 'lider',
 'url': 'https://www.lider.cl/supermercado/product/Lucchetti-Fideos-Cabellitos-B
olsa/296761'}
2018-09-17 14:41:41 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 4542,
 'downloader/request_count': 9,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 9,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 612918,
 'downloader/response_count': 9,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 9,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 80,
 'finish_reason': 'shutdown',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 17, 17, 41, 41, 696000),
 'item_scraped_count': 6,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 17,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 8,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 9,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 9,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 9,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 83,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 83,
 'spider_exceptions/IOError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 17, 17, 41, 0, 969000)}
2018-09-17 14:41:41 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (shutdown)

C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\U\8VO SEMESTRE\Ingeniería de Software II\Proyecto\Scrape
o>
```

it stopped because when I saw an error I stopped it and so did not make the cmd log very long thanks

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get any exceptions (if so - please include the full traceback if any)? What encoding is your database set to use?

Comment: @JonClements the database encoding is UTF8

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with Scrapy, but I believe your problem may be what you suspected - the encoding.

---

I see here that you've encoded the URL:

```
item['url'] = direccion_url.encode("utf-8")
```

However, this is the only thing that you have encoded.
You have mentioned

> it has an ñ in the url **and in the product name**

You have not encoded the product name.

```
item['name_prod'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//span[@class="product-descript"]/text())').extract_first()
```

Try changing the above code to:

```
item['name_prod'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//span[@class="product-descript"]/text())').extract_first().encode("utf-8")
```

Any other fields with the potential of having a special characters should be encoded, as well.

Comment: yeah I've edited the code so many times... but I tried that too but it doesn't work either :/ thanks!